# Regarding the VizierR catalogue

Tags: star, temperature

I want to build a Machine Learning model to approximate effective temperatures of stars based on their B-V index but there aren't that many catalogues that include that. I came across the Vizier catalogue (http://vizier.u-strasbg.fr/viz-bin/VizieR-3?-source=V/19/data) and I wanted to be sure if that's a catalogue for individual stars that I can leverage.

Or, do you know what other resources could help in that regard? Or suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: There is no "VizieR catalogue" - VizieR is a service giving access to a large number of astronomical catalogues. The one you've linked to is "Masses and Ages of Stars in 68 Open Clusters" by A. Piskunov (1980).

Comment: There is more to your question than it first appears. The effect of variables/binaries, surface gravity between dwarfs and giants and the metallicity will cause additional spread in a Teff vs (B-V) color relation. [This paper](https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1086/301490/fulltext/) could give you some pointers into what is involved and the data sources (many of which should be in the VizieR service)

Comment: Thank you both for your input. You are right @astrosnapper, the idea is to complement the Hipparcos data with a Temperature variable that is not there. I'm not an astrophysicist/astronomist, I'm just very interested in the subject and I'm trying to play around with data visualization tools. I'm not interested in building a truly comprehensive model, but rather a close approximation. In fact, all of this started when I got into a podcast about an Introductory Astronomy course from the Ohio State U, and the professor said that the B-V index is a proxy measurement of Teff

Comment: As a starter, if you use their Equation 2 from the paper and only keep the c0,c1,c2 & c3 terms, you could see how that compares against either the Piskunov catalog or the data source in the paper [Vizier link](http://vizier.cfa.harvard.edu/viz-bin/VizieR?-source=J/A+A/339/858)

Comment: Hi @astrosnapper, thanks once more. One final question: are all logarithms for things like log.Teff of the Piskunov using a base 10 right? I'm getting some very weird temperature readings like a star of 800 000K

Comment: Yes, log to base 10. For reference, the Sun has $T_{eff}$=5777K and log Teff=3.76